# Convert Vec<&T> to &[T] without allocation

Tags: rust

#### Problem Statement

I am trying to call `fn some_api_function()` which takes `&[T]` as parameter. To generate that parameter for the function, I tried to call `flat_map` on a Vec of Vecs (which itself buried inside RefCell). But I have trouble convert Vec<&T> to &[T]. I'd preferably avoid `Copy` or `Clone` the entire dataset for performance reason, as `some_api` just need to read-only borrow.

Code to illustrate:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
pub struct EnvVar {}

pub struct Arena {
    services: RefCell<Vec<Service>>,
}

pub struct Service {
    env_vars: Vec<EnvVar>,
}

pub fn some_api(env_vars: &[EnvVar]) {}

fn main() {
    let arena = Arena {
        services: RefCell::new(vec![Service {
            env_vars: vec![EnvVar {}],
        }]),
    };
    let env_vars: Vec<&EnvVar> = arena
        .services
        .borrow()
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|compose_service| compose_service.env_vars.as_ref())
        .collect();

    some_api(&env_vars);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=472608b19fb480ab07084f4896d94d10))

Errors:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:27:14
   |
27 |     some_api(&env_vars);
   |              ^^^^^^^^^ expected slice, found struct `Vec`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&[EnvVar]`
              found reference `&Vec<&EnvVar>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: Your actual problem is that you want a `&[T]`, but you have `&Vec<&T>`, which derefs to `&[&T]`, not `&[T]`. You'll need to add a `.copied()` or `.cloned()` in your chain after `flat_map`.

Comment: Thank you @PitaJ. Is there a way to avoid clone or copy for performance reason? some_api don't really need a owned copy, just read-only borrowing  is fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible, and here's why:

Imagine that each `T` takes up 500 bytes. Meanwhile each `&T`, being a 64-bit address, takes only 8 bytes. What you get is:

- A `&[T]` is a reference to a slice of contiguous `T`s, each 500 bytes. If the slice had 20 `T`s that contiguous block of memory would be 20 × 500 bytes = 10 KB large.
- A `Vec<&T>` containing 20 elements would have a bunch of addresses side-by-side and would only need a block of 20 × 8 bytes = 160 bytes.

There is no cheap way to turn a 160-byte block of `&T`s into a 10 KB block of `T`s. Their memory layouts are not compatible. Your only options are:

1. Clone the objects.
2. Change the caller to build a `Vec<T>` instead of `Vec<&T>`.
3. Change the function to accept `&[&T]`.

Comment: Thanks! I could also flatten the `Vec of Vecs` and store indices in the child structs.